# Do I need to disable my firmware password to use Migration Assistant?

Tags: migration-assistant, firmware-password

I'm moving to a new machine from an old machine with a firmware password. I seem to recall reading when I set up the firmware password long ago that the simple migration process will not work from a machine with a firmware password. Is this true in 10.9? If so, what special steps do I need to take to migrate from a machine that has a firmware password?

Comment: I've found an [old article](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mac/2005/05/17/tiger.html) (this may be the one I read when I set up the password) but nothing more recent to confirm that this is still the correct procedure.

Comment: I think this may be obsolete. The newer versions (maybe since 10.5) allow you to run migration assistant on the source computer as well.  If you transfer over the ethernet instead of as a mounted hdd, I don't think the firmware password would get in the way.